# How to populate POJO from JSP without using ModelDriven

Tags: java, jsp, parameters, struts2, ognl

I would like to initialize my POJO class from JSP without using `ModelDriven`.

**For example:**

In JSP -
`username` and `password` input fields.

There is a POJO `user` with `username` and `password` fields.

How to initialize this POJO?

Comment: Are you using ModelDriven?

Comment: A JSP generates an html page, it is the request, the post which is then set on the action. If your action has a property called user, then your request must contain a key with user.username and user.password with appropriate values.

Comment: @RomanC No Not using model driven

Comment: @Quaternion Any example will be helpfull

Answer (score 0):

Without using `ModelDriven` if the POJO is a property of your action it should have been initialized and have getter. POJO user should be a property of your action bean

```
private User user = new User();
public User getUser(){return user;}
```

the `User` should have properties for fields such as `username` and `password` with getters and setters.

The action should be configured to the default interceptor stack to include [`params` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/parameters-interceptor.html) which will populate your action bean.

In JSP you should prefix input field names with `user.`. So it has

```
<s:textfield name="user.username"/>
<s:textfield name="user.password"/>
```

The value in the name attribute is an OGNL expression, which evaluate to `getUser().setUsername()` and `getUser().setPassword()`.